Serpapi Google Patents Details API Search Credits
I'm in an REU program and we're trying to create a program in Python that will scrape the text of all relevant patents of a particular query. I've been doing this by first using the Google Patents API (through https://serpapi.com/google-patents-api) to get the patent IDs of all the relevant patents. Then for each patent ID, I use the Google Patents Details API to get the full text and write it to a .txt file. The problem is this uses up a search credit for every patent it finds.
Does anyone know of a way to just get the full text of all the patent IDs found without using a search credit for each one? This is my first time using APIs so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Thanks!
I tried looking into how I can do it in a different way. But I wasn't able to find anything.

Unfortunately, Google doesn't provide the full patent text in the Google Scholar search results. To get the patent's details and full text, you must click on the actual patent, which is a separate request.
Because of this, when you obtain the patent's IDs using SerpApi's Google Patents API, you need to execute a separate request to the Google Patents Details API with each ID to retrieve its full text. Each of these requests will cost one search credit.

Hi. Thanks for your answer. I noticed that it also costs one search credit for each page when I am using the Google Patents API to search for patent IDs. Do you know if there is a way to limit the search credit use to one per query instead of one per page? Thanks!
